# How to Create Dynamic Array Variable Name in ExtJS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, extjs

I have an array variable like this:

```
var subPriceSelectedIdxArray = [];
```

in the other i have a generate counter variable like this :

```
int counter = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;1++)
{
counter += 1;
}
```

i want to combine both of them variables because i need a dynamic variable. So i have a dynamic variables like subPriceSelectedIdxArray1, subPriceSelectedIdxArray2, subPriceSelectedIdxArray3, subPriceSelectedIdxArray, etc...

i create this code:

```
listeners: {
        select: function (selectionModel, selected, idx, opt) {
            window[subPriceSelectedIdxArray + index].push(idx);
        }
```

But it gets error when i push idx to `window[subPriceSelectedIdxArray + index]`. The error is variable undefined.

is it possible to create dynamic array variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is possible. But not recommended.

Let's just answer the questions first. In order to decalare a variable name like `subPriceSelectedIdxArray2` dynamically, you have to append it to the `window` as you are doing, but in this way:

```
window['subPriceSelectedIdxArray' + index] = idx;
// if index is 1, this will create a variable called subPriceSelectedIdxArray1
// if index is 2, this will create a variable called subPriceSelectedIdxArray
```

This variable will have nothing to do with the `subPriceSelectedIdxArray` and it won't be an array, it will be a `Number`.

All that being said, it looks like what you want is an array, since you want one variable in which to store multiple variables and look them up by their index. This is the correct way to do what you want to do. Maybe you have a good reason not to? If so, why?

For that you should do:

```
var subPriceSelectedIdxArray = []
```

and:

```
select: function (selectionModel, selected, idx, opt) {
   // Make sure this array is defined
   subPriceSelectedIdxArray[index] = subPriceSelectedIdxArray[index] || [];
   subPriceSelectedIdxArray[index].push(idx); }
```

or:

```
select: function (selectionModel, selected, idx, opt) {
   // Make sure this array is defined
   subPriceSelectedIdxArray[index] = subPriceSelectedIdxArray[index] || [];
   subPriceSelectedIdxArray[index][idx] = idx; }
```

Comment: Big Thanks Silva for the answer. I create dynamically generate grid in extJs. Every grid have a generate id. That's why i need a dynamic array variable like above to distinguish one grid to another grid.

Comment: Why not use an array with arrays inside of it? Just curious (Also, maybe we can mark the question as resolved then? :))

Comment: i will try that way, i don't think about array with arrays inside before .. haha thanks .. ok let's mark the question haha

Comment: That's the fun part about JavaScript. It's really flexible for that kind of stuff. Good luck!